# What is the job title for a person who communicate with software vendors, report analysis to CTO and develop software with vendors' API?

Tags: job-description, title

I was interviewed for a startup bank. Their job title is banking developer, and its job description is actually different from what they are looking for.

During interview, I clearly understand their job responsibilities.
They are:

1. communicate with software vendors for banking
2. report analysis of software vendors' software and their API to CTO
3. develop web, android, and ios banking app with software vendors' API
4. ... responsibilities of a software engineer [in summary]
5. ... responsibilities of a developer [in summary]

I understand 3 and 5 are for developer position, 4 for software engineer position. But what is the job title for 1 and 2, is it system analyst?

Well, I'm looking for a job title for 1 to 5.

Comment: Startups often combine roles and job titles are arbitrary, they can be anything. Banking developer seems close enough, but software engineer could probably cover them all in a startup.

Comment: IMO these are all common responsibilities of a software engineer. Often people think that a software developer only writes code. But working together with clients, vendors, partners, and stack holders needs analysis and communication skills as well. Especially when you are a senior engineer or team/tech lead you will probably communicate more than actually write code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. IT Coordinator
2. IT Analyst ,Application Support Analyst, Systems Analyst
3. ["insert technology name here"+ Developer] : HTML Developer, Android Developer etc
4. Applications Engineer (for IOS, android bank app) , Web/Software Engineer (for web app or window app)
5. same with 3. programmer/developer term is interchangeable

extra note

Architect - **one who design** (**in business and technical term**) : planning work flow of software/system 'what will this product do', 'user login -> bring them to main menu -> show their transactions', etc

Engineer - **one who design** (**in programming term**) **and assign** it to Developer: specify that Architect's plan 'how data will be stored', 'refer by id', 'how to authentication user' etc

Developer - **one who write** : make that Architect & Engineer's plan come true, write code

Analyst - **one who read/test** : self-explanation , checking requirement, judging plausibility, verify code, 'is it good enough?, can it be optimized? if yes, how?'

but in reality one position often have to take responsibility from other position as well. like Developer need to test their code, Engineer have to be one who coding first structure/foundation of program/software, Architect have to go get user requirement with Analyst

so don't rely on Job title alone, please read job requirement carefully

Source: https://www.thebalancecareers.com/list-of-information-technology-it-job-titles-2061498